# The importance of the order in domain controler names for setting an LDAP server, is there any reason?

Tags: rhel, ldap, autofs

I wonder if there is any reason to speficically put the domain controlers in the proper order, when configurung a LDAP server using autofs.
For example if specify on a RedHat/CentOS the dc domain controlers in this order :

```
 ou=example, dc=hostname1,dc=people
```

the LDAP is active and I may see it.

But if by a simple "mistake" I  write

```
 ou=people, dc=hostname1,dc=example
```

I do not see any mounted LDAP server, what it is exactly the meaning of the ou and dc domain names and where I could look to see which order I have to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of LDAP as a tree ([example](http://ldapman.org/articles/tree_design.html#example)). Thus, `ou=example,dc=hostname1,dc=people` will traverse the tree starting at the root `dc=people` and passing its child `dc=hostname1` before arriving at `ou=example` as a child node of `dc=hostname1`.

If you mix that order LDAP isn't able to traverse the tree. In your second example it will struggle finding the root element `dc=example` and you'll just get a message telling you that there is no such path in your directory tree. (check your logs.)

Comment: The example is very clear, how many dc or ou domains may I have ? and is there any LDIF file where I could see how the tree looks like?

Comment: I don't know how your LDAP might look like, but you can at least take a look at it using e.g. ldapsearch or an LDAP browser or dump the tree to a ldif file an use what ever editor you prefer. But explaining that is far to much for a comment. Just gave you some search terms, so use google or file another question ;-)